# Does SRP feed tight coupling?

Tags: functions, single-responsibility, coupling

I designed a function which, afterwards, I noticed it is clearly doing 2 very different tasks in the same time.

So now I am thinking to split it into 2 different functions, each one of them doing only what it should do ([SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)). Obviously, one of these functions will call to the services of the other one.

But I wonder if this is really a good decision because I tend to think this call increases  tight coupling [as per this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)#Solutions) (?)

So my question is: does SRP increase tight coupling?

Comment: No, it’s quite the opposite since your 2 functions can now be reused by other functions.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but the send link I shared in my edited post says this increases coupling ... unless if I misunderstand that

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ: The highest form of coupling between pieces of code is to have them in the same function. That coupling is so high, the code might as well be considered to be one piece.

Comment: I perfectly agree with you. On the other hand, a function is too dependent on the function it calls, is not this a tight coupling increase somehow? @BartvanIngenSchenau

Comment: By splitting the functions, at least one of those functions will have absolutely no dependency on the other.     You could decouple them altogether by using higher-order functions, in which case neither function would depend upon the other.

Comment: "a function is too dependent on the function it calls, is not this a tight coupling increase somehow?"  First, compared to what?  Second, the dependency between one function that calls another is on the signature, behavior *as well as the name* of the function.  Of those three, the name dependency is the tightest, since it prevents substitution.  This can be alleviated by injecting the function, e.g. supply function as parameter (i.e. higher order functions as per prior comment).

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ No, you sitill have coupling but less than before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### SRP applies to classes and modules:

There's a lot of confusion out there about SRP. Here an **[article of Uncle Bob](https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2014/05/08/SingleReponsibilityPrinciple.html)**, who "invented" SRP, that explains it much better than I could.  In short:

- SRP is not about what the class does (the responsibility **of** the class). So it doesn't force you to break down classes into tightly coupled twins just because they would perform several things.
- SRP is about the reason to change (the responsibility **for** the class). It encourages encapsulation and facilitates the principle of least knowledge, which combined should lead to less coupling.

#### Should functions do one thing ?

Is his book *Clean Code*, [Uncle Bob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_C._Martin) recommend that functions inside a class or a module ["*Do one thing*"](https://herbertograca.com/2016/09/03/clean-code-3-functions-by-robert-c-martin-uncle-bob/).  It may sound like SRP but is something very different.  Together with "*Keep it small*", and "*One level of abstraction per function*", it promotes a proper functional decomposition into smaller parts that are easier to understand and maintain.

Of course, a function will depend on the sub-functions that were created to decompose it.  Inside the same class, coupling is unavoidable. But this is not a problem as long as you don't expose these internal details to the outside world.

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ Exactly  ! The "do one thing" (principle for functions) is often confused with SRP (principle for classes and modules), because "one" suggests "single". But these are two different principles with different purposes. So SRP does not increase coupling; on contrary.  But the "do one thing" may create coupling (I prefer in this case to call it "dependencies", since it is unidirectional) inside a class or module, without increasing coupling between different classes

Answer (score 3):

One of the key benefits of low coupling is that it reduces the number of things you need to consider simultaneously to understand a single component of a system -- allowing among other things for easier debugging, easier maintenance, and better extendability. A reasonable way to answer your question is to consider whether or not [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) would improve your code with respect to these metrics.

My claim is that **SRP has the ability to reduce coupling**, but that reduced coupling is not guaranteed. I'll illustrate this with two scenarios.

#### Scenario 1 (don't do this)

- Start with one mega function `foo()`.
- Note that `foo()` violates SRP, so re-factor it into `bar()` and `baz()`.
- As your application grows, other parts of the code wind up depending on `bar()` and `baz()`.
- Customers and use cases change over time, so eventually `foo()` needs a modification. Most of the logic in `foo()` is implemented in `bar()` and `baz()`, so **to change behavior in `foo()` we change the behavior in `bar()` and `baz()` instead**.
- Now everything breaks.

Even though SRP has the ability to reduce coupling (at least I'm claiming it does), in this example the programmer is treating `foo()`, `bar()`, and `baz()` as a single unit AND they have the additional complexity of that unit being split between multiple function definitions and maybe even multiple files. The SRP was in name only and had no real benefits because of how the functions were being used.

#### Scenario 2 (reduced coupling with SRP)

- Start with one mega function `foo()`.
- Note that `foo()` violates SRP, so re-factor into `bar()` and `baz()`.
- As your application grows, other parts of the code wind up depending on `bar()` and `baz()`.
- Eventually `foo()` needs a modification, but we don't have an appropriate low-level component lying around with the desired functionality, so we **make a new function** `bizz()`.
- Now `foo()` consists of `bar()` and `bizz()`, and everything else still works fine.

In this example, it is easy to reason about the behavior of `foo()` because we're treating its two constituent parts as **atomic**. They have a well-defined behavior, and combined they make up `foo()`. When those behaviors are insufficient, we make a new atomic component with the desired functionality. This approach easily leads to code re-use and prevents API-breaking changes. Moreover, all the components are small enough and can be easily reasoned about and proven to be correct.

**Extras:** Even though SRP can decrease coupling in a sense, if functions are not grouped appropriately it has the potential to have every module in an application depending in some way or another on every other module. Designing the entire system to be loosely coupled is every bit as important as designing functions to be loosely coupled, and for roughly the same reasons.

Answer (score 3):

From any reasonable point of view, the action of extracting of part of function into another function does not cause any harm which can attributed to a coupling. What may be bad is that later somebody reuses the extracted functions without careful consideration is it really the same functionality (as in scenario described in another answer). So you should consider it carefully, and limit usage of the sub-functions, by using the measures provided by your language (private methods etc.)